# Using DbQuery in linq join -> Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a query (`DeliveryDates`) and a dbset (`Products`) in EF Core and I want to join them in linq.

I tried this:

```
var list = await (from d in _financeContext.DeliveryDates
                  join p in _financeContext.Products on d.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                  select new
                          {
                          }).ToListAsync();
```

But I get this error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DbQuery'.  'Join' not found. (CS1936)

Is there anyway to join a dbquery and a dbset in linq ?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a using directive.

Answer (score 0):

join is a Linq function. It looks like you don't add a using to System.Linq;

```
using System.Linq;

var list = await (from d in _financeContext.DeliveryDates
              join p in _financeContext.Products on d.ProductId equals p.ProductId
              select new
                      {
                      }).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var firstlist=_financeContext.DeliveryDates.tolist();

var list = await (from d in firstlist
                  join p in _financeContext.Products on d.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                  select new
                          {
                          }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This is a absolutly bad solution. toList() will load every row from the table. This will lead to a horrible performance.